# How to replace unwanted entries with the most frequently used

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
salutation= c("Mr","Mrs","not reported","Mrs","Mrs", "Mrs","Company","Mrs","not reported","Company"),
```

Expected Outcome:

```
      DB <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
salutation= c("Mr","Mrs","Mrs","Mrs","Mrs", "Mrs","Company","Mrs","Mrs","Mrs"),
```

Good morning!

This time I need to replace the "not reported" entries with the most frequently used salutation (in the example it´s Mrs) in the data set. Because in my original data set it´s not clear whats the most used salutation is it´s necessary to find out in at first what the most used salutation is and then reenter it to the data set.

Tried it with an ifelse function but this was not working:

```
DB$salutation = ifelse(DB$salutation == "not reported", max(salutation), as.factor(DB$salutation))
```

Hope you guys have some ideas to solve it easily :)

Comment: Fix your data: there is a missing `)` at the and a useless comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by finding the most frequent salutation:

```
most_freq <- names(which.max(table(DB$salutation)))
```

Then you can assign this value to each case which is "not reported":

```
DB$salutation[DB$salutation == "not reported"] <- most_freq 

#> DB
#   orderItemID salutation
#1            1         Mr
#2            2        Mrs
#3            3        Mrs
#4            4        Mrs
#5            5        Mrs
#6            6        Mrs
#7            7    Company
#8            8        Mrs
#9            9        Mrs
#10          10    Company
```